# Why can't I read a file when mysql is configured with secure_file_priv empty?

Tags: mysql

`secure_file_priv` is already set to empty, and there is content in the file. But I can't read it.

```
mysql> SELECT @@version;
+-------------------------+
| @@version               |
+-------------------------+
| 5.7.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT LOAD_FILE('/tmp/flag')
    -> ;
+------------------------+
| LOAD_FILE('/tmp/flag') |
+------------------------+
| NULL                   |
+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT LOAD_FILE('/tmp/flag');
+------------------------+
| LOAD_FILE('/tmp/flag') |
+------------------------+
| NULL                   |
+------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

in bash can read by mysql user with cat /tmp/flag

```
$ su -c 'cat /tmp/flag' mysql
flag{444}
```

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql   10 7  18 11:21 flag
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mysql root    10 7  18 14:23 flag1
-rwxrwxrwx 1 kali  kali    11 7  18 14:25 flag2
```

The first 2 load_files can be read. The last flag2 doesn't.

sudo aa-status

```
➜  disable sudo aa-status                         
apparmor module is loaded.
7 profiles are loaded.
7 profiles are in enforce mode.
   /sbin/dhclient
   /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action
   /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper
   /usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script
   /usr/sbin/mysqld
   /usr/sbin/tcpdump
   docker-default
0 profiles are in complain mode.
2 processes have profiles defined.
2 processes are in enforce mode.
   /sbin/dhclient (814) 
   /usr/sbin/mysqld (1450) 
0 processes are in complain mode.
0 processes are unconfined but have a profile defined.
```

How do I turn off apparmor's protection of mysqld?

Comment: Do you have [AppArmor](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/security-apparmor) or [SELinux](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SELinux) running?

Comment: Didn't use either one. I'm using Ubuntu 16.

Comment: Did you check (`aa-status`)? I think AppArmor is loaded and enabled by default in 16.04.